# Why would the USSR use a US citizen to create the Winter Soldier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

I can easily see a Soviet boss using captured Western technology to advance Soviet might. It happened in real life, quite often (Nuclear weapons program, rockets, etc...)

But as someone who grew up in USSR, the idea that anyone in USSR would want a **citizen of the USA**, of all people, to be the "superhero" Winter Soldier, seems to stretch credibility.

I can see why Hydra would want to use Barnes (they care about Hydra, not the EverLasting Glory of The Homeland of Elephants). **But any non-Hydra USSR boss approving the idea... well, that seems way too far-fetched even in a universe that has a talking intelligent Racoon**.

## Is there any in-universe explanation why a **US citizen** was used, *instead* of a proper Soviet citizen (like for Red Guardian program, for example)?

<sub>I'm OK with either MCU-specific, or comic Marvel answers</sub>

Comment: Maybe culpability? Blame the Americans.

Comment: The Winter Soldier isn't a superhero, he's a super-villain.

Comment: @Valorum - he is a super-hero **to the Soviets**

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Nope. He's a covert assassination asset. Even his identify (and existence) are a closely guarded secret.

Comment: Deniability? If word gets out about your secret KGB assassin, it's nice to have a convenient excuse like "look, he's not even Russian!"

Comment: I won't watch the films again just to confirm this, but according to the fan wiki he received a version of the Super Soldier Serum in Hydra custody. After that, he might be simply have been the best available raw material - after all, Winter Soldiers were brainwashed, so it doesn't really matter what and who they were before. Plus having their dirty work against the US done by an US American sounds like very Soviet idea of having fun.

Comment: I'd throw this back and posit that the Winter Soldier is not actually a 'hero' per se. He's a tool sure, but not a hero. He's kept secret. Take the Red Guardian for example, he's a publicly known and sort of celebrated super soldier.

Comment: Why did the Ottomans use Christian kids to create their Janissary? Sounds similar to me.

Comment: @Kheldar **not at all** similar. They didn't have nationalist pride the way USSR did, which was not even a thing at that point in history, never mind in pre-Ataturk Ottoman empire.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To I'm not literate enough in the subject of nationalistic identity in the Ottoman empire to prove or disprove this, but I would point to various works of art of the period gifted to the Kingdoms of France, England, or to German potentates, at least displaying some premices of such a feeling. An interesting research, I guess :D

Comment: In Soviet Russia, brain washes YOU!

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To, actually, Kheldar has a good point. Note that he said *Christian*, not German or Croatian or Hungarian.

Comment: @Cadence Believe that was a big part of the plot of the whole Call of Duty: Modern Warfare video game line, at least how the war started.  "And remember - no Russian!"

Comment: In Soviet Russia, fun has YOU!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to confidential files obtained by Steve Rogers in *[Captain America Vol. 5 #11](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_5_11)*, the comicbook version of Barnes was selected to be the Winter Soldier for two primary reasons.

Firstly, [Vasily Karpov](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Vasily_Karpov_(Earth-616)) -- the head of the department directly overseeing the project -- liked the idea of turning an "American symbol" back against Russia's enemies. It's made clear in these files that he knew Barnes was formerly Captain America's partner, [Bucky](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Buchanan_Barnes_(Earth-616)).

> MAJOR GENERAL VASILY KARPOV, HEAD OF SPECIAL SECTION DEPARTMENT X
>
> Project: Winter Soldier - June 1954
>
> Volkov's man at MI-6, Parsifal, has proved his worth. The schematics for Advanced Robotic Appendages and Attachment he provided two months past were revolutionary. Our science team finished a working prototype and attached it to the American without incident, With the new appendage in place, clearance was given for Department X to begin work on the Winter Soldier Project.
>
> **It has long been my plan to turn this American symbol back against our enemies. He was no aid to developing our own Super-Soldiers, but he will still be a valuable tool, in the right hands.**
>
> <sub>*Captain America Vol. 5 #11*</sub>

[image]

<sub>*Captain America Vol. 5 #11*</sub>

The second reason Barnes was selected was "because he walk[ed] and talk[ed] just like [Americans], because he exude[d] "America" with his every breath", allowing him to move among American and Allied troops without suspicion.

> It was our own experiments in Mental Implantation during Sensory Deprivation that provided the breakthrough. And because of the American's memory loss, it was quite simple. We were able to reprogram the American's mind.
>
> We gave him a purpose, and we made him loyal to no one but us.
>
> Once that was accomplished, we had simply to train and prepare him for a field evaluation.
>
> **Hopes are high that he will be a successful operative. I believe, because he walks and talks just like them, because he exudes "America" with his every breath, that the enemy will never see him coming.**
>
> Report - Codename: Winter Soldier - Field Test, 5 November 1954
>
> All objectives achieved. Codename: Winter Soldier encounters no difficulty on mission.
>
> **As predicted, Americans and allies mistake him for one of their own. Allow him unimpeded entrance into West Berlin.**
>
> **Winter Soldier spends evening in Berlin nightclub among many U.S. and U.K. servicemen, unsuspected.**
>
> Jeep overturns at 02:45 killing three soldiers en route to base from nightclub. Crash not investigated. Assumed drunken roadway incident.
>
> On mission completion, Codename: Winter Soldier crosses border, returns to handlers without incident. Future assignments under evaluation.
>
> <sub>*Captain America Vol. 5 #11*</sub>

[image]

<sub>*Captain America Vol. 5 #11*</sub>

Comment: I always thought it also had something to do with torturing Cap's sidekick. A bit like the Joker trying to reach Batman by attacking the people he cares about, as it would hit him harder.

Comment: A very "Manchurian Candidate" explanation, and makes perfect sense, from that standpoint. You never have to worry about him being identified because he did something "culturally inapproriate," because it's his own culture that he's infiltrating.

Answer (score 20):

Bucky was a weapon of HYDRA, a secret super assassin. He was not a USSR creation. Arnim Zola created Bucky whilst working for Schmidt back during the war. As he’s a weapon of HYDRA he does not fall under the jurisdiction of any country either.

> **Arnim Zola:** Sergeant Barnes... The procedure has already started. You are to be the new fist of HYDRA.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*</sub>

Comment: I'd push it even further and say he [wasn't a hero at all](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253500/why-would-soviet-russians-use-an-american-to-create-the-winter-soldier#comment696996_253500)

Comment: I gather the question is asking about both MCU and the comics. In the comics he was found by the USSR and turned into the winter soldier.